# Add contact to users contaclist in aWindows 8 Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-8, contacts, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a Windows 8 Metro App with c#

In the app you can search persons in a phonebook. 
Is there a possibility to add a found contact to the users contact-list?

I know you can browse the contacts with the Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Provider, but I can't see how you can add a contact.

thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do so through the [Contact Picker Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh464906).  Use [ContactPickerUI.AddContact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.provider.contactpickerui.addcontact).  This will bring up a UI that the user can use to add the Contact you hand it.  You cannot add a Contact without bringing up a Contact Picker UI.  The [Contact Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1) gives an example of adding a contact.