# How to add contact using contactPickerUI in metro app in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, contacts

I have gone through [Add contact to users contaclist in aWindows 8 Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451966/add-contact-to-users-contaclist-in-awindows-8-metro-app/11457920#11457920)

But i am still not clear.i mean do we need to create contactpickerUI or it's default? How to bring that UI? Can i add the contact at run-time like as i can add new contact, edit the contact in people hub.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already check out the example code here

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1

Once you've got that code the parts you are after are in the file Constants.cs, there you will see a couple of partial classes, App and MainPagePicker which hook up the contactPickerUI property.