# Add people to HUB via Windows Store app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to write a Windows Store app that can add a contact to the Contacts Hub. The fields are filled in automatically and the user only needs to confirm that the data is correct to add the contact. I am developing in C#. Is there any API available yet? Or does anyone know any other method so I can accomplish this?

Comment: +1, though I'd be very surprised if the WP API allowed anyone to tamper with something as critical as contacts.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451966/add-contact-to-users-contaclist-in-awindows-8-metro-app

Comment: @Alex indeed, but can't close with an open bounty.

Comment: The answer can be found in the duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11457920/254041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , there are so many methods . What i do is : 
Try using Live SDk in your application by including it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826532 , and the link also contains the sufficient code to start with .

You can take the contact information from there automaically and can use the Roaming storage for storage of information or can use any cloud storage if you want to update on the basis of multiple users.